# Python pandas: fill a dataframe with data from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty pandas dataframe as displayed in the first picture.

What I like [first dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stbVK.jpg)

So, many, many Pfam IDs as columns and many different gene IDs as indices. Then I have a second dataframe like this. 
[second dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBOl0.jpg)

Now what I would like to do is getting the data from the second into the first, doing this I simply like to write a 0 in each Pfam column that has no entry for a particular gene ID, and a 1 in each case a gene has a Pfam.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post data as image, it will be very difficult for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry, will post a working example next time. Just that my tables were gigantic and I was reading them from files, but sure, I'll create a min. working example next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume the first dataframe is named `d1` and the second is `d2`

```
d1.fillna(d2.groupby([d2.index, 'Pfam']).size().mul(0).unstack())
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot!